# Getting warning on audiosource.play Can not play a disabled audio source how to fix it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Not sure if the problem is that I'm using dontdestroyonload. This is the script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject gameAudio;
    public static AudioManager audioManager;

    private AudioSource audioSource;
    private string sceneName;
    private bool currentScene = false;

    void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this);

        if (audioManager == null)
        {
            audioManager = this;
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        // Create a temporary reference to the current scene.
        Scene currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();

        // Retrieve the name of this scene.
        sceneName = currentScene.name;

        audioSource = gameAudio.GetComponent<AudioSource>();

        var mainmenumusic = GameObject.Find("Main Menu Settings");
        audioSource.volume = mainmenumusic.GetComponent<AudioSource>().volume;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (BackToMainMenu.gameSceneLoaded && currentScene == false)
        {
            audioSource.Play();
            currentScene = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (currentScene && BackToMainMenu.gameSceneLoaded == false)
            {
                audioSource.Stop();
                currentScene = false;
            }
        }
    }

    //Called when Slider is moved
    public void changeVolume(float sliderValue)
    {
        audioSource = gameAudio.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        audioSource.volume = sliderValue;
    }
}
```

The warning is on the line :

```
audioSource.Play();
```

Can not play a disabled audio source
UnityEngine.AudioSource:Play()
AudioManager:Update() (at Assets/My Scripts/AudioManager.cs:40)

For sure the audio source component is not disabled at any time.

I tried this check :

```
if (BackToMainMenu.gameSceneLoaded && currentScene == false)
        {
            audioSource.gameObject.SetActive(true);

            if (audioSource.gameObject.activeInHierarchy && audioSource.enabled)
            {
                audioSource.Play();
            }
```

It's getting to the line :

```
audioSource.gameObject.SetActive(true);
```

but then when getting to the IF the object is not active it's false again :

```
if (audioSource.gameObject.activeInHierarchy && audioSource.enabled)
```

The activeInHierarchy is false.

This script the AudioManager sit in the Main Menu scene using a prefab name Game Audio.

[Audio Manager settings in the main menu scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWEid.jpg)

Then in the Main Menu I also have this script that get reference to the AudioManager script and the AudioManager get the volume value of the music in the Main Menu :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using System;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using System.Linq;

public class Settings : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource[] audioSources;
    public AudioMixer audioMixer;
    public TMP_Dropdown resolutionDropdown;
    public TMP_Dropdown qualityDropdown;
    public Text musicText;
    public Text sfxText;
    public Slider[] audioSliders;
    public Toggle fullScreenToggle;
    public GameObject audioManager;

    private Resolution[] resolutions;

    private void Awake()
    {
        audioSources = GetComponents<AudioSource>();

        resolutionDropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener(new UnityAction<int>(index =>
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("resolutionvalue", resolutionDropdown.value);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();

        }));

        qualityDropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener(new UnityAction<int>(index =>
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("qualityvalue", qualityDropdown.value);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();

        }));

        fullScreenToggle.onValueChanged.AddListener(new UnityAction<bool>(index =>
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("fullscreen", boolToInt(fullScreenToggle.isOn));
            PlayerPrefs.Save();

        }));
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        qualityDropdown.value = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("qualityvalue");

        var resolutions = Screen.resolutions.Where(resolution => resolution.refreshRate == 60).ToArray();
        resolutionDropdown.ClearOptions();

        List<string> options = new List<string>();

        int currentResolutionIndex = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < resolutions.Length; i++)
        {
            string option = resolutions[i].width + " x " + resolutions[i].height;
            options.Add(option);

            if(resolutions[i].width == Screen.currentResolution.width &&
                resolutions[i].height == Screen.currentResolution.height)
            {
                currentResolutionIndex = i;
            }
        }

        resolutionDropdown.AddOptions(options);
        resolutionDropdown.value = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("resolutionvalue", currentResolutionIndex);
        resolutionDropdown.RefreshShownValue();

        float musicvolume = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("musicvolume");
        float sfxvolume = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("sfxvolume");

        musicText.text = musicvolume.ToString();
        sfxText.text = sfxvolume.ToString();
        audioSliders[0].value = musicvolume / 100f;
        audioSliders[1].value = sfxvolume / 100f;

        fullScreenToggle.isOn = intToBool(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("fullscreen", 0));
        
    }

    public void SetResolution(int resolutionIndex)
    {
        if (resolutions != null)
        {
            Resolution resolution = resolutions[resolutionIndex];
            Screen.SetResolution(resolution.width, resolution.height, Screen.fullScreen);
        }
    }

    public void SetMusicVolume(float volume)
    {
        audioMixer.SetFloat("musicvol", Mathf.Log10(volume) * 20);
        musicText.text = Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();

        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("musicvolume", (float)Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));

        audioManager.GetComponent<AudioManager>().changeVolume((float)Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
    }

    public void SetSfxVolume(float volume)
    {
        audioMixer.SetFloat("sfxvol", Mathf.Log10(volume) * 20);
        sfxText.text = Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();

        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("sfxvolume", (float)Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));

        if (!audioSources[1].isPlaying)
            audioSources[1].Play();
    }

    public void SetQuality(int qualityIndex)
    {
        QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(qualityIndex);
    }

    public void SetFullscreen(bool isFullscreen)
    {
        Screen.fullScreen = isFullscreen;        
    }

    int boolToInt(bool val)
    {
        if (val)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    bool intToBool(int val)
    {
        if (val != 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

I'm doing it in this function :

```
public void SetMusicVolume(float volume)
        {
            audioMixer.SetFloat("musicvol", Mathf.Log10(volume) * 20);
            musicText.text = Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();
    
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("musicvolume", (float)Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
    
            audioManager.GetComponent<AudioManager>().changeVolume((float)Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
        }
```

At this line :

```
audioManager.GetComponent<AudioManager>().changeVolume((float)Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
```

This is the main menu Settings script and both audio sources of the main menu music and sfx :

[The Settings script settings in the main menu and the audio sources of the musioc and sfx in the main menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUstv.jpg)

Then when making a new game the Main Menu scene is unloaded and it's loading the Game scene.

In the Game scene I have the Game Data where all the game play stuff is and the Game Audio that is the prefab I'm using also in the Main Menu inn the AudioManager script :

[Game scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yHHG.jpg)

[Game Audio prefab in the Game scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UGia.jpg)

The idea is to get the volume of the music in the Main Menu and when changing the volume in the Main Menu to set the volume also to apply take affect also in the Game scene audio source.

The music in the main menu(main menu scene) is not the same music in the game scene. but I want that when I'm changing the volume of the music in the main menu also the sfx it will change the volume to the music and sfx in the Game scene.

I have one audio mixer with two groups :
Main Menu Audio and Game Audio all music and sfx are exposed.

[Audio Mixer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/japbZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like either the component `AudioSource` **is** disabled

could check it via

```
Debug.Log($"AudioSource is {audioSource.enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled!"}", this);
```

so you would have to enable it

```
audioSource.enabled = true;
```

or the `GameObject` it is attached to itself or any of its parents is inactive. Could check it using

```
Debug.Log($"AudioSource is {audioSource.gameObject.activeInHierarchy ? "active" : "inactive!"}", this);
```

so you would need to activate it

```
audioSource.gameObject.SetActive(true);
```

or check both before trying to play the source depending on your needs

```
if(audioSource.enabled && audioSource.gameObject.activeInHierarchy) audioSource.Play();
```

Comment: I edited my question added more information and screenshots. I tried your solution the audiosource gameobject is false not active in hierarchy but even if I set it to be enabled true active it's still not active when getting to the checking. So I added more information and screenshots of what I did and trying to do please take a look if you can. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like none of these images is of a running instance, right? They are all from edit mode ...